# Tensorflow: select specific elements from each row of a tensor for a NN with variable labels

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to build a neural network where the labels and the number of labels change on input. For example, I could have a final layer of 10 units that represent the logit of their class, but sometimes I will only need units [1,3,4] to calculate cross entropy, some of the units [3,4,5,7] etc.

I tried using different combinations of map_fn, gather, py_fn and while_loop but no one seems to be in my case. Another way might be to list all types of label combinations (I call them network heads) and find some conditional constructs that allow me to choose one based on the value of a placeholder. But I'm not sure how to implement it.

For example:

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,3])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, 3])

... to_do ...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(to_do, feed_dict={x: [[1, 3, 4], [3, 7, 8]], y: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]})
```

Here I need something that return [[1],[7,8]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no matter. There was a very easy way to get the probabilites I needed for cross-entropy.

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,3])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, 3])

probabilities = tf.where(tf.equal(y,1), tf.exp(x), tf.zeros_like(x))
normalizing_sum = tf.reduce_sum(probabilities, 1, keep_dims=True)

probabilities/=normalizing_sum

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(probabilities, feed_dict={x: [[1, 3, 4], [3, 7, 8]], y: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]})
```